# Nginx: How to deny public access to endpoint in proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx

I have a subdomain **app.example.com** set up which connects to a phoenix/elixir backend project using sockets on port 4000 using proxy_pass.

In my project, I have an endpoint called `/admin/auth`, which my PHP script (on **example.com**, not **app.example.com**) will send HTTPS cURL posts to. However, the `/auth` endpoint is highly sensitive and I only want the local host 127.0.0.1 to send posts to that endpoint, no one else.

I have the following Nginx config, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
upstream app {
  server 127.0.0.1:4000 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=60s;
}
server {
  server_name app.example.com;

  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  listen 443 ssl;

  location = /admin/auth {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Cluster-Client-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }
}
```

How would I do this? Also, how could I also deny public access to the entire `/admin/` folder which has many more sensitive endpoints within it?

My cURL script on example.com, which runs on localhost 127.0.0.1, looks something like this. Currently, the script is not working with the Nginx config above, but it does work if I remove the `location = /admin/auth` block in the Nginx config:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://app.example.com/admin/auth");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```